# Delimiter with space and read space after delimitor

Tags: java, delimiter

How do I take in space as string after a delimiter (" "), because only their first name is being read.

```
public class readfile {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        String readFile = "";
        int i;

        if (args.length == 1) {
            readFile = args[0];

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(readFile));
            List<String> read = new ArrayList<String>();
            String rLine;
            while ((rLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] items = rLine.split(" ");

                if (items[0].equals("Name")) {
                    for (i = 1; i < items.length; i++) {

                        String name = items[1];

                    }

                    System.out.println("Name is " + items[1]);
                }
            }
        }

    }
}


Classlist.txt

Name Alice Mark
Name Rebecca Appel
Name Jonah BullLock Jacob
Name Daniel Ethan Aron
```

Output:

Name is Alice
Name is Rebecca
Name is Jonah
Name is Daniel

Comment: What output do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Change below lines:

```
                       for (i = 1; i < items.length; i++) {

                            String name = items[1];

                        }
```

to:

```
                  String name = "";
                  for (i = 1; i < items.length; i++) {

                        name += items[i];

                    }
```

Comment: i tried it, but it become

Name is AliceMark
Name is AliceMarkRebeccaAppel
Name is AliceMarkRebeccaAppelJonahBullLockJacob
Name is AliceMarkRebeccaAppelJonahBullLockJacobDanielEthanAron

Answer (score 0):

If the format of the file containing the names is always the same, i.e. starting with 'Name' and with exactly one space between parts of names, you could use the following code instead:

```
while ((rLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    if (rLine.startsWith("Name ")) {
        String name = rLine.substring(5);
        System.out.println("Name is " + name);
    }
}
```

The output then is e.g. `'Name is Jonah BullLock Jacob'` for the third line.